# Having the same endpoint name on multiple slices of injectEndpoints

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I have the following code:
**userSlice.js** file

```js
const userSlice = mainApi.injectEndpoints({
   endpoints: (builder) => ({
      createOne: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
         url: '/users'
         method: 'POST',
         credentials: 'include',
         body: payload,
      })
      })
   })
})

export const { useCreateOneMutation } = userSlice
```

**roomSlice.js** file

```js
const roomSlice = mainApi.injectEndpoints({
   endpoints: (builder) => ({
      createOne: builder.mutation({
      query: () => ({
         url: '/rooms'
         method: 'POST',
         credentials: 'include',
         body: payload,
      })
      })
   })
})

export const { useCreateOneMutation } = roomSlice
```

I want to be able to use the name `createOne` in the both slices [roomSlice, userSlice],
However, I can't... because if I used createOne() of the roomSlice in one of my components, it would think that it's the one belonging to userSlice, (even though I am importing the `useCreateOneMutation` from the right file) so what I have done is to use the property `overrideExisting: true` as follows:

**userSlice.js** file

```js
const userSlice = mainApi.injectEndpoints({
   endpoints: (builder) => ({
       // ...
   }),
   overrideExisting: true
})
```

**roomSlice.js** file

```js
const roomSlice = mainApi.injectEndpoints({
   endpoints: (builder) => ({
       // ...
   }),
   overrideExisting: true
})
```

But it still does not work as expected, what am I doing wrong?

btw I'm not getting any warning as described in the docs
[image: Loading...]